# SmartTarget 2014 SP1

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

I have followed below steps but nothing is displayed On Page.

1. Created a Simple Promo Content with Title and Description.
2. Created a Component with Required SmartTarget TBBS as dynamic component presentation.
3. Published it to devserver(Not sure it went till FredHopper or not).
4. Created Promotion in SMartTarget Ui (Can see in FredHopper UI too).
5. Created a Page with Required TBB and Published it to dev.

After Publishing Aspx is having below code.

```
        <smarttarget:Promotions MaxItems="1" Region="Header" runat="server"> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <smarttarget:PromotionalItems runat="server"> 
                    <ItemTemplate> 
                            <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:55-11167-64" ComponentURI="<%# Eval(&quot;ComponentUri&quot;) %>" TemplateURI="<%# Eval(&quot;TemplateUri&quot;) %>"/> 
                    </ItemTemplate> 
                </smarttarget:PromotionalItems> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
            <FallbackContent> 

 <br>No Promotion for You </br>

            </FallbackContent> 
        </smarttarget:Promotions> 

    </smarttarget:Query>
```

Here, Fallback content is gettign dispalyed on Page No promotion is getting rendered.

So Did I missed any step?
Did I need to do anything extra?
Where component goes when publishing to fredhopper?

Thanks
Harish Sharma

Comment: What does the Promotion trigger on and is it being triggered?

Comment: What's the deal with the Component created in step 1? Is it the same as the one in step 2 or different? Which one of them did you choose to return in the Promotion? Whichever one, you should check the Preview in Fredhopper to see if your item was published correctly.

Comment: Reyes, Promotion trigger is Visitor Browser is chrome. And how to check is it being triggered or not?

Comment: Please see and answer @PeterKjaer's questions. You can use Chrome or explicitly trigger the Visitor Browser through the Footprint setting in Experience Manager. SmartTarget is meant to be tested in Experience Manager. For testing down to the ADF, you might use Peter's [ADF test page](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/AmbientDataFrameworkTestPage). Otherwise someone else might explain better how to check the specific claims (and thus triggers) while testing.

Comment: as Peter mentioned in Fredhopper business manager there is a Preview button which takes you to the FH Preview page, by default http://yourfhserver/preview/?preview_seo=false&fh_location=//catalog01/en_US. There you can see all default promotions and all items present in the FH index. You can also on the right rail enable any trigger or your choice to see if a promotion is triggered. No need for XPM to test those from a technical perspective. XPM is nicer of course for business users to test their promotions, once the system is configured properly.